# iOS canvas cannot capture the video DOM which is not on the document

Tags: javascript, ios, canvas

I played a Video tag in the background. Then I want to capture it with canvas, to calculate it`s frame rate. It works fine on the PC Chrome. But when I got it on the iPhone(XR, iOS 14) , the bad news appeared. It seems that video can only be collected when the Video tag plays in the foreground.

So can I capture the video frame by frame in the background, without append the Video element to the document? (on iOS)

Some code:

```
  videoEl = document.createElement("video");
  videoEl.style.width = "160px";
  videoEl.style.height = "120px";
  videoEl.srcObject = mediaStream;
  videoEl.play();

  const canvasEl = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvasEl.width = 160;
  canvasEl.height = 120;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(videoEl, 0, 0);
  const frame = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: Hi Zeyu, would be useful if you framed your problem in a question statement. What are you stuck with?

Comment: Okay. I will add my problem.